# answer for mysql sore procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

```
Create Proc getinfo
(
@Studentid int,
@karan varchar(200) out
)
As
Begin
     select @karan= Firstname+' '+Lastname from tbl_students where Studentid=@studentid
End
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoZA.png)

Comment: please answer my question

Comment: your question ?

Comment: which is i posted above

Comment: in above it is showing 1 sp nothing else where is ur question ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttoZA.png

Comment: thats my question

Comment: ↑↑↑↑↑-picture...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the getinfo proc. Your exec statement is not quite right and need to declare and assign a variable to accept the returned value, and you need a select to see it

```
declare @name varchar(100)
set @name = ' '
execute getinfo @studentid = 11000,@karan = @name output
select @name name
```

note this is a sql server answer since that appears to be what you are using.